# Mercurial Changegroup hook varies based on branches

Tags: mercurial, hook, mercurial-hook

Is there an existing hook in Mercurial which, like changegroup, allows actions to take place on a push, but allows me to do multiple actions (or vary them) based on which branches are affected by the changesets therein?

For example, I need to notify a listener at an url when a push is made but ideally it would notify different urls based on which branch is affected without just blanketing them all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are no branch-specfic hooks, but you can do that logic in the hook itself.  For example in your `hgrc`:

```
[hooks]
changeset = actions-by-branch.sh
```

and then in your `actions-by-branch.sh` you'd do:

```
#!/bin/bash
BRANCH=$(hg log --template '{branch}' -r $HG_NODE)
BRANCH=${BRANCH:-default}  # set value to 'default' if it was empty

if [ "$BRANCH" == "default" ] ; then
   do something
elif [ "$BRANCH" == "release" ] ; then
   do something else
else
   do a different thing
fi
```

Notice that I used a changeset rather than changegroup hook.  A single changegroup can have changesets on multiple branches, which would complicate the logic.  If you do decide to go that route you need to loop from `$HG_NODE` all the way to `tip` to act on each changeset in the changegroup.

Comment: I guess `${BRANCH:=default}` should be `BRANCH=${BRANCH:=default}`.

Comment: It works  as written. From the bash man page "${parameter:=word}
              Assign  Default  Values.   If  parameter  is  unset or null, the
              expansion of word is assigned to parameter.  The value of param-
              eter  is  then  substituted.   Positional parameters and special
              parameters may not be assigned to in this way."  If we wanted the more verbose assignment statement we'd use `:-` instead of `:=`.

Comment: Ok, I've figured out the problem. Bash tries to run the value of `$BRANCH` as a command. That's why I got a `mybranchname: command not found` error message. So, you either need the assignment or use a bash no-op (`: ${BRANCH:=default}`)  to avoid this error.